# VBA tool to create powerpoint slide from excel?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, powerpoint

Currently I have develop an excel sheet to extract data. 
The output sheet (text + graph) should be exported to a PowerPoint slide.

Is there a way to do this with the help of a macro?

This is how it currently looks like. Ideally, I would add a button 'create slide', which triggers a macro to create a slide with this layout.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but you need to provide a lot more information for anyone to help. What help are you looking for -- someone to build this for you or help building it yourself? What have you tried? Please update your question to show what code you've come up with and the specific problems you're having so we can address those specific issues.  See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Many thanks! I will update the request based on the progress made

Comment: you could try https://slidefab.com .

 
it would also help you with your other request which I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491199/extract-excel-graph-to-powerpoint-template