# Extract excel graph to powerpoint template

Tags: python, excel, vba, graph, powerpoint

I have an Excel sheet in which I can select a city (100 different ones) and then a graph will be generated for that city.

I would like to create a PPT with 100 different slides, one for each city. 
For these slides I have a template, so what I would like to achieve is:
 - Loop through all 100 cities
 - Copy the generated graph and paste as image at a specified location and size in the PPT slide

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this with either VBA or Python?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To copy and paste an excel range into powerpoint using VBA check this link : [Copy & Paste An Excel Range Into PowerPoint With VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba)

Hope it will help you! Thank you! :)